# Groovy - handling exception - how to get Oracle error code

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'm running a Groovy script in jMeter test plan like:

```
import groovy.sql.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;

def url = vars['url']
def user = vars['user']
def password = vars['password']
def driver = vars['driver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

try{
    def result = sql.call("{? = call MY_FUNCTION(?,?)}", [Sql.NUMERIC, vars.get('MY_VAR'), 'MY_PARAM']);
} catch (Exception ex) {

    log.error "getMsg: " + ex.getMessage(); 
}

finally{
    sql.close();
}
```

which, on exception, returns whole Oracle error message:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated... blah blah

How could I get only the Oracle specific error code number, ex. 'ORA-00001' or '00001' or '1' (preferably not using regex or substring)?

I tried using [OracleDatabaseException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseException.html) class but Groovy doesn't seem to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't want regular expressions you can use [SQLException.getErrorCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode--) function like:

   ```
   } catch (SQLException ex) {

       log.error "getMsg: " + ex.getErrorCode()
   }
   ```
2. However if the error will not be SQLException or derivative the above catch block will not work. So in order to be on the safe side you can use [Groovy Find Operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html) `=~` like:

   ```
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       println("getMsg: " + (ex.getMessage() =~ "(ORA-\\d+)")[0][0])
   }
   ```

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.